# chart.js v4.1.1 legend position not working

Tags: javascript

I've tried a few things to get the legend to appear to the right of the pie chart but nothing is working so far.

I've tried these in the options but the legend always appears on top, which I assume is the default.

```
legend: {
    position: 'right',
},

// or this
plugins: {
  legend: {
     display: true,
     position: 'right',
     align: 'center'
  }
}
```

I've been through a bunch of posts and went through the documentation on the chart.js website. What am I missing?

Here's the code

```
const projectChart = document.getElementById('projectChart');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/GglProjectPriority",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});

function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var _data = data;
    var _chartLabels = data[0];
    var _chartData = data[1];

    var options = {
        type: 'pie',
        title: 'Project Priority',
        data: {
            labels: _chartLabels,
            datasets: [{
                data: _chartData
            }]
        },
        legend: {position: 'right'},
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
        },
        // plugins: {
        //     legend: {
        //         display: true,
        //         position: 'right',
        //         align: 'center'
        //     }
        // }
    };
    new Chart(projectChart, options);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue on https://jsfiddle.net/ or some replicable envs?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

I have options nested within the options.

code:

```
var options = {
    type: 'pie',
    title: 'Project Priority',
    data: {
        labels: _chartLabels,
        datasets: [{
            data: _chartData
        }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: "right",
                align: "center"
            }
        }
    }
};
```